# Route [password.update] not defined.Laravel

Tags: laravel, routes, change-password

The user should be able to change his password when he is logged in. But always  get i the same error. "Route [password.update] not defined." 
I find the route are not in my rout list.

The routes are set in web.php and named in the controller. Where is the mistake?

Routes

```
//Change Password Routes
Route::get('/setting', 'Auth\UpdatePasswordController@index')->name('password.form');
Route::post('/setting', 'Auth\UpdatePasswordController@updatePassword')->name('password.update');
```

Controller

```
class UpdatePasswordController extends Controller
{
    /*
     * Ensure the user is signed in to access this page
     */
    public function __construct() {

        $this->middleware('auth');

    }
    /**
     * Show the form to change the user password.
     */
    public function index(){
        return view('/setting');
    }

    /**
     * Update the password for the user.
     *
     * @param  Request  $request
     * @return Response
     */
    public function updatePassword(Request $request)
    {
        $this->validate($request, [
            'old' => 'required',
            'password' => 'required|min:6|confirmed',
        ]);

        $user = User::find(Auth::id());
        $hashedPassword = $user->password;

        if (Hash::check($request->old, $hashedPassword)) {
            //Change the password
            $user->fill([
                'password' => Hash::make($request->password)
            ])->save();

            $request->session()->flash('success', 'Your password has been changed.');

            return back();
        }

        $request->session()->flash('failure', 'Your password has not been changed.');

        return back();

    }
}
```

view

```
<form action="{{ route('password.update') }}" method="post" role="form" class="normagin sky-form">
          {{csrf_field()}}
```

Comment: Did you try clearing the routing cache?

Comment: Try cleaning your routes cache with `artisan route:clear`.

Comment: I get the same error message

Comment: Hmm, another reason for a missing route would be if you didn't load the routes file. Could you paste your RouteServiceProvider?

Comment: run `php artisan route:list` and check (a) the route is in the list and (b) that you have named the route and (c) that you are calling it exactly (take note of plurals, etc)